# How to use SPF with AWS new MAIL FROM support?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, spf, dkim

Amazon AWS recently added support for custom MAIL FROM domains in their Simple Email Service (SES). I have configured one for my domain as `bounce.mydomain.com`. I went through the wizard on the UI and it added some records to my domain in Route53, but when I check at http://dkimvalidator.com it tells me that my DKIM configuration is OK, but my SPF is not:

```
Result: none (No applicable sender policy available)


Result code: none
Local Explanation: mydomain.com: No applicable sender policy available
spf_header = Received-SPF: none (mydomain.com: No applicable sender policy available) receiver=ip-172-31-3-128.us-west-1.compute.internal; identity=mailfrom; envelope-from="myaddress@mydomain.com"; helo=a8-60.smtp-out.amazonses.com; client-ip=54.240.8.60
```

What else do I need to add (besides the records the wizard adds to Route53) to enable SPF for a custom MAIL FROM domain?

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote. Please let me know how I can improve the question!

Comment: Based on the "No applicable sender policy available" message, it looks like you don't have a SPF record for the domain in the DNS.
A SPF record is a TXT record with the following format:
`v=spf1 mx a ?all`. This is just an example record, your actual record may require other mechanisms.

Comment: Lars is correct, all you need to do is create a TXT (type 16) SPF record in DNS, with amazon SES I think you need the SPF record to look like `v=spf1 mx a include:amazonses.com -all`, the mx and the a is probably not needed, but it doesn't hurt to include them, just in-case. Once you get it set up you can test the basics DKIM, SPF, etc using [mailtest](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/) - It's a good question, I up-voted, not sure why someone will down vote it also.

Comment: Thanks! @henry That mailtest link looks awesome. Thanks for sharing.